# How to make a List look like iphone menu

Tags: css, list, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I need a List look like iphone menu, see this picture

[image: http://www.demogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/img-01281.png]

My list actually is this

[image]
I can't obtain a same look

my js code

```
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        model  : 'Contact',    
        getGroupString : function(record) {
            return record.get('menu')[0];
        },

        data: [
            {menu: '<img src="images/summary2.png" height="42" width="42" /> Shipment Summary ',item:'1'},
                {menu: '<img src="images/detail2.png" height="42" width="42" /> Shipment Details ',item:'2'},
            {menu: '<img src="images/documents2.png" height="42" width="42" /> Shipment Documents ',item:'3'}
        ]
    });

    SL.views.mainMenuBottomBar = new Ext.List
    ({
            id: 'MBB',
            fullscreen: false,
            centered: true,
            cls: 'settingscls',
            disableSelection: true,
            scroll: false,
            dock: 'bottom',
            itemTpl : '<tpl for="."><div class="x-list-group-items">{menu}</div></tpl>',
            grouped : false,
            indexBar: false,
            onItemDisclosure: 
                    function(record)
                   {
                        if(record.get('item')=='1')               {
                       }
                        ...
                   },
       store: store
    });
```

my css code

```
.settingscls
{
    background:transparent;
}
.settingscls .x-list-disclosure
{
        margin-top:0.6em;
        right:1em !important;
        -webkit-mask:none;
        -webkit-mask-box-image: url('images/list-arrow.png');
}
.settingscls .x-list-item
{
    background:white;
    left:10px;
    right:10px;
    bottom:10px;
     -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0.4em ;
         -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0.4em;
     -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0.4em;
         -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0.4em;
}
```

-In the css I can't apply border to first and last item list

-The text appears in vertical align bottom

-the font not same to iphone menu

-the right margin or padding works

Please help me

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Check out the similar question asked on Sencha Touch forum:-

- [How to create something like iPhone settings menu?](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?115231-How-to-create-something-like-iPhone-settings-menu)

Output :-

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I can't apply border to first and last item list in my code.

Comment: Yes you can.  Use jQuery and have a proper selector. http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-first-child-last-child-selector-example/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you container has padding to the left and right, and that the ul is displayed as a block element, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/P9pSG/4/

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I can't apply border to first and last item list